# Python Append Function?

Tags: python

The function will return a list containing all the letters found in both strings. All the letters returned should be lowercase.
There should be no duplicate letters in the list returned by your function.

Example:

string_scramble('GraSS', 'grilled cheese') should return: ['g','r','s']

```
def string_scramble(string_one, string_two):

string_one = "hello there"
string_two = "welcome to town"


a = list(set(string_one) & set(string_two))
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong with what you've written?

Comment: It returns the following:

Answer (score 0):

`a = set(string_one).union(string_two)`

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 33, in test_string_scramble
AssertionError: <function string_scramble at 0x7f96dc63ec80> is not an instance of (<class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>)

Comment: I don't know man, I hade like 25 questions to do by Sunday @ midnight (24 hours from now). I done 1-24 in a few hours.. Been stuck on this one since Friday

Comment: you probably need to return a list list(a)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lambda expression that solves your question:

`scrambler = lambda str1, str2: list(set(str1.lower())&set(str2.lower()))`

Just try

`scrambler('GraSS','grilled cheese')`

Comment: unfortunately it will not let you use lambda function :(

Answer (score 0):

```
def string_scramble(string_one, string_two):
    new_list = []

    for letter in sorted(set(string_one.lower())):
       if letter in sorted(set(string_two.lower())):
          new_list.append(letter)
    return new_list

print(string_scramble('grass', 'grilled cheese'))
```

output:

```
['g', 'r', 's']
```

I added .lower() because it appears as if you want to ignore the case based on your question. In Python, we can simply convert the entire string to lower case. The set function will return the output that you are looking for.

Also of interest, I used sorted here so that you can keep the strings in order in the set, because a set is generally unordered.

Answer (score 0):

```
string_one = "hello there"
string_two = "welcome to town"
set(string_one.lower()) & set(string_two.lower())
->>> {'t', 'l', 'e', ' ', 'o'}
```